# Phenotype of a possible gene mutation

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, pathology, human-physiology, cardiology

I have noticed multiple cases where patients had similar body characteristics :

1. decreased ability to gain weight (slim)
2. they are capable of sleep only 6 hours or less with normal functioning (although they prefer long sleep)
3. increased susceptibility to ligaments and connective tissue damages
4. CVS morbidities: example angina

I think its a good opportunity to ask here what could this mutation be and how would someone search for such characteristics in gene mutation databases.

I searched a lot using ordinary way and found a possible match ( ADRB1 receptor mutation) it causes the affected person ability to sleep less hour and CVS symptoms but i can't confirm if that's the case with the first and third characteristics.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the symptom of Marfan syndrome.

Comment: @bob1, marfan syndrome would have a different presentation  (you will notice their long extermities and eyesight problems ) not quiet like this case.